# Using AJAX to call OpenWeather API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am trying to design a simple html page that displays data from the OpenWeather API using AJAX. For some reason, my parameters, latitude and longitude, are not being put into the URL. I'm sure it is small, but I can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

My JavaScript Code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    function getWeather() {
        var latitude = document.getElementById("lat").value;
        var longitude = document.getElementById("long").value;
        request.open('GET', 'https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&appid=547fa6dfa44cff13fa92bba2c465b366', true); 
        request.send();
        request.onreadystatechange = displayData;
    }


    function displayData() {
        if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
           var resultData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
           var temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
           var windspeed = document.getElementById("windspeed");
           temperature.value = resultData.main.temp;
           windspeed.value = resultData.wind.speed;
           document.getElementById("resultset").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
     }

     window.onload = function() {
         var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
         btn.addEventListener("click", getWeather, false);
    }
```

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <h1>Weather Report</h1>
   </header>
   <article>
      <h2>Weather Data</h2>

         <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm" novalidate>
         <fieldset id="zipset">
            <label for="lat" id="lat">Latitude:</label>
            <input id="lat" type="number" />
            <label for="long" id="long">Longitude</label>
            <input id="long" type="number" />
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="resultset">
            <label for="temperature" id="temperature">Temperature:</label>
            <input id="temperature" type="text" />
            <label for="windspeed" id="windspeed">Wind Speed:</label>
            <input id="windspeed" type="text" />
         </fieldset> 
         </form>
       <button id="btn">Submit Coordinates</button>
   </article>
   <script src="js/weather_report1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: please create a working example as js fiddle. i created one and it doesnt seem to do anything at all https://jsfiddle.net/qug19nrp/

Comment: ok, you got the id "lat" for both the label and the input. leave the id only for the input field and remove it from the label. that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I dont see an element with the id="zip". same with city and state. And ur giving multiple elemnts the same id. lat, long, temperature and windspeed are given twice which u never should do.

Comment: That was left over from another API I was playing around with. I meant to delete it. It is now.

Comment: have u removed the duplicate ids on the labels aswell?